# Can Haskell do the job of Make?

Tags: haskell, makefile

Are there implementations of *make* (make as in makefiles) in Haskell around? I do not a mean a clone with the same interface but something that does the same job in a similar way. Reason for asking is that the make language has a functional style so Haskell should be able to the same job naturally.

Comment: Maybe [shake](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake)

Comment: Any language, functional or not, could be used to implement `make`. The fact that `make` uses a functional style does not limit which languages could be used to implement it.

Comment: In case you are interested in the theoretical background of build systems, you can read [Build Systems a la Carte](https://simon.peytonjones.org/build-systems-a-la-carte-theory-and-practice/) by A. Mokhov, N. Mitchell and S. Peyton Jones.